# BIRT - Failed to load the JNI shared Library (JDK)

Tags: java, jvm, java-8, birt

I am unable to run BIRT.exe an Business intelligence reporting tool, it's throwing error as specified below in the image:

[image]

Tried fixing this watching the below video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QETYeZzl6kA

Which stated jvm.dll needs to copied from :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\server
```

to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\server` directory. But still unsuccessful.

**JDK version :** `jdk1.8.0_45`

**BIRT version :** `birt-report-designer-all-in-one-3_7_2`

Please assist me to solve this issue

Comment: Since you have a native `.EXE` which tries to load a JVM-specific `.DLL`, you should check whether the architecture of the executable program and the JVM match, i.e. that you don’t try to let a 32 Bit program use a 64 Bit JVM or vice versa…

Comment: Yeah, to avoid this conflict i have installed both 32bit and 64bit jdk. Also changed the Environmental variable path to 32bit and tried if that will work, but it was unsuccessful. And later just cross checked with `java -version`. It was still showing 64bit instead of 32bit which got changed in path variable. Any clues w.r.to this?

Comment: Well, I don’t know which variable you changed…

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of jdk i.e version 8 has problems with BIRT. So i downgraded to version 7 and everything working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to link it with 86-bit version of java. You can have it on PATH, but in order to make modern apps happy, just create a symbolic link:
cd to birt's dir and run something like this:

```
mklink /D jre "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_191"
```

and yes, jre 8 works fine for me.